# FINEUPLOAD pass the ID as parameter

Tags: php, fine-uploader

i got this divs

```
<div id="thumbnail-uploader_1" class="thumbnail-uploader">
<div id="thumbnail-uploader_2" class="thumbnail-uploader">
```

and this Jquery call

```
$('.thumbnail-uploader').fineUploader({
request: {
    endpoint: '/core/ajax/add_avatar.php',
    params: {
    one: function() {
        return this.id;
     }
    }
},
multiple: false,
validation: {
    allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
    sizeLimit: 551200 // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes
},
text: {
    uploadButton: 'Klikněte nebo sem přetáhněte soubor'
}
}).on('complete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
if (responseJSON.success) {
    $(this).append('<img src="/uploads/categories/' + fileName + '" alt="' + fileName + '">');
    $('.qq-upload-list').fadeOut(2500);
}
});
```

all i want to do is to pass the ID of the used uploader. but with this call, i got undefined value of the parameter "one" when i try to use it in "add_avatar.php" which is handler. i use the global array REQUEST over there to check if the value pass. but its undefined.

does anyone have some idea how to pass the ID in my php script? i will have more instances of this uploader there so i have to check for which record im changing the avatar.

Comment: the script is going well, its uploading, crop-resizing and showing the result as an IMG

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using jQuery, maybe this is what you are looking for.

```
return $(this).attr('id');
```

Comment: still i got the value "undefined". have no idea how to pass the ID. in the php script i need to INSERT a new record in DB with and ID of category.

Comment: My bad, it wasn't supposed to be capital 'ID'. Does it work now?

Answer (score 0):

i solved it by creating the jquery calls  for every iterations of category and i changed the selector from class to ID like:

```
$('#thumbnail-uploader_1').fineUploader({.....
$('#thumbnail-uploader_2').fineUploader({.....
```