# Get div ID of element attached to Fine Uploader

Tags: jquery, html, file-upload, fine-uploader

I am using fineuploader version 3.2. I have multiple instances of fineuploader embedded on a single HTML page like this

```
<div id="file-uploader_1" class="uploader">
<div id="file-uploader_2" class="uploader">
```

And this is how I attach fineuploader

```
$('.uploader').fineUploader({
request: {
    endpoint: './uploadfile',
    params: {
    imageid: function() {
        return this.id;
     }
    }
},
multiple: false,
validation: {
    allowedExtensions: ['jpeg', 'jpg', 'gif', 'png'],
    sizeLimit: 551200 // 50 kB = 50 * 1024 bytes
},
text: {
    uploadButton: 'Changepic'
}
}).on('complete', function(event, id, fileName, responseJSON) {
if (responseJSON.success) {
    imgs[this.id]="data:image/jpg;base64,"+ data;
}
});
```

I want to pass the id of the div attached to fineuploader to the fileupload request. However I see that 'undefined' is returned wherever 'this.id' is referenced. I also tried using this.attr('id') instead and get an error "Uncaught TypeError: Object # has no method 'attr' ".

I found a similar question here([FINEUPLOAD pass the ID as parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16158976/fineupload-pass-the-id-as-parameter)) however the solution seems too crude. Can someone suggest a better solution, rather than repeating the same code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can loop through the elements and call fineUploader on each, retrieving each ID in the process:

```
$('.uploader').each(function() {
  var uplId= $(this).prop("id");
  $(this).fineUploader({
    request: {
        endpoint: './uploadfile',
        params: {
        imageid: function() {
            return uplId;
         }
        }
}
...
});
```